# Android Firebase API initialization failure. Given String is empty or null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, gradle

So I've wasted my whole day, and finally decided to ask you guys for help. I'm just trying to integrate Firebase with my Android Studio project. So this is the error log that I'm getting when the app launches..

```
8-27 04:23:13.285 17651-17651/cr.logics.smashanarchy E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
                                                                 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1758)
                                                                     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1733)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6335)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5927)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5866)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1703)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbp.zzgf(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdkg.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdlq.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                                     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1758) 
                                                                     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1733) 
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6335) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5927) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5866) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1703) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I did some research, and looks like this line means that it didn't managed to read the google-services.json file..

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
```

This is what I'm getting whenever I'm syncing my gradle files..

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
:Application:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:preArm7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:checkArm7DebugManifest
:Application:preArm7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2520Library
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2520Library
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2520Library
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2520Library
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2520Library
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42520Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerV4Impl1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection1120Library
:Application:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1120Library
:Application:prepareArm7DebugDependencies
:Application:compileArm7DebugAidl
:Application:compileArm7DebugRenderscript
:Application:generateArm7DebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateArm7DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateArm7DebugResources
:Application:mergeArm7DebugResources
:Application:processArm7DebugManifest
:Application:processArm7DebugResources
:Application:generateArm7DebugSources
:Application:preArm7DebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareArm7DebugAndroidTestDependencies
:Application:compileArm7DebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Application:processArm7DebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:Application:compileArm7DebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateArm7DebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateArm7DebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateArm7DebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:mergeArm7DebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:processArm7DebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateArm7DebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:preArm7DebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareArm7DebugUnitTestDependencies
:Application:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 9.205 secs
```

So in the beginning its says..

```
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
```

although I already did.
This is how my gradle files looks like..

Root gradle file

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

app gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "25.0.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "cr.logics.smashanarchy"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 14
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }

    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "S3DClient"
        cppFlags.addAll(["-I${file("src/main/jni/AIModels")}".toString(),
                         "-I${file("src/main/jni/S3DX")}".toString(),
                         "-I${file("src/main/jni")}".toString()])


        ldFlags.add("-Wl,--no-whole-archive")
        ldFlags.addAll(["-lopenal", "-lssl", "-lcrypto", "-lGLESv2", "-lEGL", "-ldl", "-llog"])
        ldFlags.add("-Wl,--no-whole-archive")
        ldFlags.addAll(["-lS3DClientNative_Android"])
        ldFlags.add("-Wl,--whole-archive")
        ldFlags.addAll([])
        ldFlags.add("-Wl,--no-whole-archive")
        stl     = ""
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {create ("arm7") {
        ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        ndk.ldFlags.add("-Lsrc/main/jni/prebuilt/engine/armeabi-v7a".toString())
        ndk.ldFlags.add("-Lsrc/main/jni/prebuilt/plugins/armeabi-v7a".toString())
        ndk.ldFlags.add("-Lsrc/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a".toString())
    }

        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        // build one including all productFlavors
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

google-services.json file is in the app folder as it should be.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure this will help.  The [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) indicate that for 11.2.0 you must use `compileSdkVersion 26`: _When you upgrade your app’s Play services dependencies to 11.2.0 or later, your app’s build.gradle must also be updated to specify a compileSdkVersion of at least 26_

Comment: Why is your buildscript block split between two gradle files?  Usually it exists in only the root build.gradle.  Also, what's this: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.3'`?  Don't you want this instead: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3`?

Comment: tried changing the compileSdkVersion to 26.. didn't helped.. also tried removing the buildscript block from the app build file.. didn't helped.. replacing the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.3' with com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3 didn't helped too :/

Comment: I don't do NDK builds and am not familiar with your build method.  This [guide for migrating to stable gradle for NDK](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental/migrate-to-stable) indicates many changes are needed to go from `gradle-experimental.0.9.3` to `gradle:2.3.3`. When you tried `2.3.3`, did you make all the changes described in the guide?

Comment: Ahmm.. let me see if I can update my project with the new gradle... Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, looks like it will take a while for the shiva team to migrate to the latest gradle version. Is there any temporary workaround for my project? like what if I create new empty project(without ndk) with the same package name,.. then build it, and copy some files to my original project?

Comment: Using the Firebase analytcs, logging events, remote config works perfectly(although I'm getting the error telling that unable to initialise Firebase), but whenever I'm trying to use the Authentication, its crashes.. giving the same, "Given String is empty or null" error.. I guess I have to do something with the google-services.json file..